# Vertical text alignment Centre & block select on li

Tags: html, css

I would like a column of buttons with text centered vertically with block select on the buttons, so that anywhere the button is clicked, it will navigate to the link.

The vertical text alignment doesn't work and neither does the block select.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul{
                width:110px;
                display:block;
            }
            li{
                background-image: url(../images/bg_th.gif);
                font: bold 10px Arial, Helvetica;
                height:55px;
                color: #999;        
                text-align:center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                width:110px;
                display:block;
            }
        </style>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="fooPage.html" target="innerPane">Button 1</a></li>         
            <li><a href="fooPage.html" target="innerPane">Button 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="fooPage.html" target="innerPane">Button 3</a></li>
        </ul>
            <iframe name="innerPane"src="foo.html"></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, there are following two things needs to be done.

1. Aligning the text of each button vertically.
2. Not just text on button but full area of the button should be clickable.

First can be solved by applying `{position:relative; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle}` to the element containing the text. Also, you need to apply `{display:table; vertical-align:middle;}` to the parent element.

Second, anchor tag should be applied to wherever you want clickable area. You can swap the a and li elements in the HTML.

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5mWdL/).

Please leave a comment if you mean something different from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you might be looking for

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9XVZ7/)

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="fooPage.html" target="innerPane"><span>Button 1</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="fooPage.html" target="innerPane"><span>Button 2</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="fooPage.html" target="innerPane"><span>Button 3</span></a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
 ul {
     width:110px;
     display:block;
 }
 li {
     background-image: url(../images/bg_th.gif);
     font: bold 10px Arial, Helvetica;
     height:auto;
     color: #999;
     text-align:center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     display:block;
     border: 1px solid gray;
 }
 a {
     display: block;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     padding-top: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
 a:hover {
     background: red;
 }
 a span {
     position: relative;
 }
```

Comment: If the button text is larger, there is a bug in your answer. The text starts with a padding-top of 40px and overflows. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/6AtXF/1/